# How do I implement functions in the C language?

Tags: c, function, compilation, header

I'm have a really hard time completing some homework, and would appreciate if anyone could sent me on the right path.

Basically, I've been asked to define a function that counts the number of iterations that occurs until a number grows larger than `10` or some number (`max`). I've made the function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int iteration(float x, int max){
    int n; 
    float y;

    for (n=0;y=0;n++) {
        y=y+x;

        if (y>=10,max) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

First off I'm not even sure if the `if` statement is correct (I don't know if it's proper code to just put a comma for "or"). After that, I'd imagine the rest of the code is okay (clarification would be greatly appreciated!).

Once this was done, I made a header file (`Count.h` where this file was `Count.c`) with just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int iteration(float x, int max);
```

And finally, I used this header in a different file, which was just the header and then the main function like:

```
int main () {
    iteration (9.8, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles fine (but not through the "make" command, when I use icc individually to create each object file, it works), but nothing gets outputted or executed.

If someone can let me know where I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it! Or if you could give me a hint, I'm sure I could figure it out. I'm getting stressed because this is just the first part of a long homework assignment, and I can't believe I can't even figure this simple stuff out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The comma operator evaluates both its operands, ignores the result on the left, and returns the one on the right.  So `if (y>=10,max)` is equivalent to just `if (y>=max)`.

Comment: This is not quite the correct site to ask this question. Also this are at least three questions so it might be better to focus on one thing at a time. Your implementation of `iteration` is not quite correct. Try using a debugger to figure out what is going on. If your makefile does not work, anyone trying to help you must see that file. Finally, for the missing output: well, there is nothing in the code that would produce any output.  I think you forgot to write `printf("result: %d\n", iteration(9.8, 5));` or something in your `main`.

Comment: Check out [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with icc, so can't directly answer your question about how to compile your project, but I suggest looking into the section of its manual about using the linker.

Comment: @Wyzard actually it's equivalent to `if (max)`. `,` has a lower precedence than any other operator, including assignment and comparison.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 3):

this isn't a great question, and I would normally just comment, but I find it harder to format comments... here is the problem, probably...

```
for (n=0;y=0;n++)
```

so in C `=` is the assignment operator, and `==` tests equality... so the resulting expression `y=0` will always evaluate to false... so this for loop will never be entered (equivalent is `while(0)`)

it looks like you don't actually care about that term, so you can either leave it blank or make it a true value... or just make it the exit criteria, so ....

```
assert (x>0.0); // otherwise the loop will never exit
for (int i = 1; ; i++) // more idiomatic to use i as a loop counter
{
     y+=x;
     if (y > max)
     {
          return i;
     }
}
return 0; // already over max
```

so you need:

```
float y = 0;
```

get rid of `n` it isn't doing anything.

or alternately you may have meant something like...

```
for( n=0,y=0;;n++)
```

which is fine but a little weird and complicated

Answer (score 0):

1. To clarify, did you include your header in your main .C file (i.e. `#include "Count.h"`)?
2. Also, you have iteration return 'n', but do nothing with it. You must either assign the returned integer to a variable (`answer = iteration (9.8, 5);`) or output it (`printf("%i", iteration (9.8, 5))`).

As long as you've included your header, your program is most likely executing as expected, but with nothing done with the returned value, it just ends without outputting anything.